# Difference between async & await, tasks and thread?

Tags: c#

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/

In this MS link,

> Cooking breakfast is a good example of asynchronous work that isn't
>   parallel.  One person (or thread) can handle all these tasks.
>   Continuing the breakfast  analogy, one person can make breakfast
>   asynchronously by starting the next task  before the first completes.
>   The cooking progresses whether or not someone is  watching it. As soon
>   as you start warming the pan for the eggs, you can  begin frying the
>   bacon. Once the bacon starts, you can put the bread into  the toaster.
>
> For a parallel algorithm, you'd need multiple cooks (or threads).  One
>   would make the eggs, one the bacon, and so on. Each one would  be
>   focused on just that one task. Each cook (or thread) would be  blocked
>   synchronously waiting for bacon to be ready to flip, or  the toast to
>   pop.

one of the example code is

```
async Task<Toast> MakeToastWithButterAndJamAsync(int number)
{
    var toast = await ToastBreadAsync(number);
    ApplyButter(toast);
    ApplyJam(toast);
    return toast;
}
```

If async and await doesnot create new thread then where does async method is executed, because async method returns Tasks, Tasks are executed with background thread pool? I'm confused

Comment: Check [this Stephen Cleary's article](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) which should answer your question in detail. I also highly recommend exploring more articles on his blog. You'll learn a lot about async/await, tasks, and asynchronous programming in general.

Comment: Asynchronous methods executed on the same single thread. Notice that asynchronous methods mostly used for accessing external resources (databse, webservice etc). When you send request current thread do nothing, but only waiting for the response. So with async-await we can use this thread to execute something else while waiting for the response.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed thank you, this post helped me a lot.

Comment: @Fabio So if I write async method for doing some calculation(or kind of related to current application) instead of external resource, this async method is waste instead I should use thread to implement this. Am I right?